# how to get the device serial number in object C or In swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Hi I am new to Objective C.
Please help me how to get the device serial number in iPhone please help me 
anyone please provide a sample application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

For iOS:

Apple does not allow developers to access a device serial number on iOS. Alternatively, they provide you with [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor):

> An alphanumeric string that uniquely identifies a device to the app’s vendor. (read-only)

For macOS:

```
var serialNumber: String? {
  let platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice") )

  guard platformExpert > 0 else {
    return nil
  }

  guard let serialNumber = (IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert, kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeUnretainedValue() as? String)?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines) else {
    return nil
  }


  IOObjectRelease(platformExpert)

  return serialNumber
}
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/leogdion/77f6143ecf793e1ba381917d4b3b286c

Comment: Link says "How To Get A Serial Number on macOS in Swift". Does this work in iOS?

Comment: @meaning-matters Ah good point - hadn't read well. Editing answer.

Comment: Be aware, this may not be what you want: https://codeburst.io/unique-identifier-for-the-ios-devices-590bb778290d

Comment: @meaning-matters good point  - although the user does not mention why they require the serial number. Should I edit my answer to include your post?

Comment: Be aware that there are two possible memory leaks in the code. 1) If you use `takeUnretainedValue()` you are responsible to release the object (ARC doesn't do it) and 2) `platformExpert` won't be released if `nil` is returned

Comment: thanks for your replay.@meaning-matters while using "identifierForVendor"  I am getting one alphanumeric value but that value is not related to device Serial number. Please help me some other alternative solution