# Pulling Apple Serial Number

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I am writing an app for the company. My goal is to control the iPads distributed to employees in the company. I made a very simple app. When the application is opened, I want to get the serial number in the image below into the serialnumberTextField.

How can I do this? can you help me?

[image]

```
let device = UIDevice.current
let serialNumber = device.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

I tried this but it's not what I want.

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52982791/how-to-get-the-device-serial-number-in-object-c-or-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Device control & management is practically zero inside the app sandbox. Any app you (or I) write will be functionally useless for this purpose.

Check out MDM which is the correct solution for the problem of group Apple device management.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement